# python isinstance gives different results in shell and wsgi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, isinstance

I have encountered a strange problem in which the same object(`agent`), when checking if it is an instance of a class(`Agents`), returns `True` in the shell, but  `False` in the wsgi server.

in the python shell:

```
In [78]: agent = Agents.by_id(566) # SQLAlchemy Table object

In [79]: type(agent)
Out[79]: models.Prepaid.Agents

In [80]: type(Agents)
Out[80]: sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.DeclarativeMeta

In [81]: isinstance(agent, Agents)
Out[81]: True
```

but when I print the same in my code - to print in the wsgi instance, it looks like:

```
# print type(agent)
<class 'models.Prepaid.Agents'>
# print type(Agents)
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.DeclarativeMeta'>
# isinstance(agent, Agents)
False
```

This is confusing, and I do not know why this is happening.

- Can someone please explain this?
- Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: if it will help I can add in the `Agents` class...

Comment: How did you obtain `agent` in your code?

Comment: As a follow up to Simeons question, how did you obtain ``Agent`` in your code?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I get it by using another `classmethod` called `by_msisdn`, which returns an `Agents` object. same as the `by_id` `classmethod`... I then pass it to a create method where the print statements are...

Comment: Which WSGI server are you using?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton we use gunicorn